# $2n$ cells were marked on an infinite triangular grid, can you always find a triangle that contains exactly $n$ marked cells?

Tags: combinatorics, open-problem

**The problem:**
*(Solve the problem for each positive integer $n$ separately)*
$2n$ cells were marked on an infinite triangular grid, is it always possible to find a triangle *(made by the grid lines)* that contains **exactly** $n$ marked cells?

**My progress:**
I managed to solve the problem for every odd integer and for $n=4,6,8,10,12$

[image: examples]

**My inspiration to create the problem:**
[my inspiration](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2112446p15300352)

Comment: Cool problem! I didn't understand the image link that you provided though, can you explain it?

Comment: The 2 image links show all the examples that I found in which you can't find a triangle that contains exactly half of the marked cells. 
The first link has the examples for odd $n$ and the second one has the examples for even $n$
The black colored cells are the marked cells

Comment: Do you have a proof for the odd case?

Comment: Lovely question. Your diagrams for odd $n$ looked convincing but I thought that writing out a proof might be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following examples for even $n\ge 4$ work.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

For $n=4k$, two cells $3,2k+3$ are not marked.

For $n=4k+2$, two cells $1,2$ are not marked.

There are no triangles which contain exactly $n$ marked cells.

*Proof* :

Let us call grid lines $L_i,R_j,H_1,H_2,H_3$ as follows :

For $n=4k$,

[image]

- Triangles made by $L_i R_jH_2$ with $i\ge j$ cannot contain exactly $4k$ marked cells since the number of the marked cells which they contain is less than $4k$.
- Triangles made by $L_i R_j H_2$ with $i\lt j$ cannot contain exactly $4k$ marked cells since the number of the marked cells which they contain is odd.
- Triangles made by $L_iR_j H_1$ with $i\ge j$ cannot contain exactly $4k$ marked cells. The reason is as follows. We only need to consider the case where the number of the marked cells which they contain is of the form $4m$. For $(i,j)=(2k+2,1)$, the triangle contain $8k$ marked cells. For $j=3$ with $4\le i\le k+2$, the number of the marked cells which they contain is less than $4k$ since the length of $AB$ is $k-2$ where $A$ is the intersection point of $H_3$ with $L_{k+2}$ and $B$ is the intersection point of $H_3$ with $R_3$. Similarly, for $j=k+3$ with $i\ge k+4$, the number of the marked cells which they contain is less than $4k$.
- Similarly, triangles made by $L_iR_j H_3$ with $i\lt j$ cannot contain exactly $4k$ marked cells.

For $n=4k+2$,

[image]

- Triangles made by $L_i R_jH_2$ with $i\ge j$ cannot contain exactly $4k+2$ marked cells since the number of the marked cells which they contain is less than $4k+2$.
- Triangles made by $L_i R_j H_2$ with $i\lt j$ cannot contain exactly $4k+2$ marked cells since the number of the marked cells which they contain is odd.
- Triangles made by $L_iR_j H_1$ with $i\ge j$ cannot contain exactly $4k+2$ marked cells since the only case where the number of the marked cells which they contain is of the form $4m+2$ is when $(i,j)=(2,1)$ for which the triangle contains $2$ marked cells.
- Triangles made by $L_iR_j H_3$ with $i\lt j$ cannot contain exactly $4k+2$ marked cells since the only case where the number of the marked cells which they contain is of the form $4m+2$ is when $(i,j)=(2,2k+3)$ for which the triangle contains $8k+2$ marked cells.$\ \blacksquare$

Comment: WOW your example is very beautiful! I'm very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

**Proof for $n$ odd**

Consider $4k+2$ marked cells arranged as per the OP's diagrams and suppose that triangle $ABC$ contains exactly $2k+1$ marked cells, where $AB$ is horizontal.

The lines $AB$ and $AC$ divide the plane into $4$ regions. Let the region containing triangle $ABC$ contain exactly $2k+1+a$ marked cells and let the directly opposite region contain $\alpha$ marked cells. Define $b,c,\beta, \gamma$ similarly and then $$a+b+c+\alpha+\beta+\gamma=2k+1. ( 1 )$$

Considering edge $BC$ we see that $a+\beta+\gamma$ is even. Similarly, $b+\alpha+\gamma$ is even and $c+\alpha+\beta$ is $0,2k-2$ or $2k$.

If $\gamma \ne 0$, then all the marked points in triangle $ABC$ are in a triangle of side $3$ units which is clearly impossible. Therefore $\gamma = 0$.

If $\alpha +\beta=0$ then $a,b,c$ are all even, contradicting equation $1$. So there are two cases:-

**If $c+\alpha+\beta=2k$.** Then $a+b=1$. Considering edge $BC$ we see that $a$ is $0$ or at least $2$. The same is true for $b$ and so this case is impossible.

**If $c+\alpha+\beta=2k-2$.** Then $a+b=3$. Considering edge $BC$ again we see that $a$ is $0,2$ or at least $4$. The same is true for $b$ and so this case is also impossible.